# I am getting HTTP 500 Server Error when I am trying to POST data to my server. I don't know what's the issue

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-post, data-processing, http-error

I get this error HTTP POST 500 (Internal Server Error).
,i am trying to post data to the url below
'...lhost:3000/data/applications' , I have sent successful request to the url '...lhost:3000/data/posts' on the same server,I don't know whats the issue with the '.../data/applications' one.i can use the get method but it gives me 500(Internal Server Error) with the post request.
thats my request body :

```
 if(method!='GET'){
        options = {
            method,
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
    }
```

,and i am calling the request by

```
export const createpo = (applId) => request.post(api.applications,applId);
```

,thats my function where i use this method

```
dataService.createpo(applId)
            .then(()=> {
              ctx.page.redirect(`/details/${ctx.params.offerId}`);
              console.log(applId);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and thats my whole function where i use this

```
export function renderDetails(ctx){

let user = authService.getUser();


dataService.getOne(ctx.params.offerId)
.then(offer => {
    
    dataService.getallapplic(ctx.params.offerId)
    .then(applicationres => {

       console.log(applicationres);

       if(!user){
          ctx.render(detailsguestTemplate(offer,applicationres));
        }
        else if(user._id==offer._ownerId){
          ctx.render(detailsownTemplate(offer,applicationres));
        }
        else if(user._id!=offer._ownerId){
          ctx.render(detailsloggedTemplate(offer,applicationres));
        }
    })
    .then(() => {


      let elementd = document.getElementById('apply-btn');
      

      if(elementd){

        elementd.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
         
          e.preventDefault();

          elementd.setAttribute('hidden','hidden');
  
          let applId = ctx.params.offerId;

    
          dataService.createpo(applId)
            .then(()=> {
              ctx.page.redirect(`/details/${ctx.params.offerId}`);
              console.log(applId);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        });

      }


    })
    
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

}

Comment: The 500 error means the server script encountered an error. What do your logs (on the server) show? There should be a filename and line number where the error occurred.

Comment: it gives my api url as an error and this line as an error, 'export const createpo = (applId) => request.post(api.applications,applId); ' ,  but there is nothing wrong with the url,its literally just '...data/applications ' thats it

Comment: It is not saying the URL is the issue, it is saying the error is occurring in that file. A 500 error is an error on the server, not the client side. So your JavaScript isn't generating the error, the file on your server is. And your server should also have a log file that logs any server errors. Checking that log will show you what line number the error occurs on so you can debug your application.